# Randomly order by display Mysql Row

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Question_ID | Question_sentence  
1           | This is a apple?  
2           | This is a car?  
3           | what number is this?
```

this is my Mysql Table with a `Question ID` and `Question Sentence`,
when i have create a page and display those question, i would like to Randomly display **ALL** the question, how do i solve this?

maybe add in a new column name `Random_ID` and will assign a random number between 0 until 9999,
and then use the following SQL statement
`SELECT * FROM Tbl_Question Order By Random_ID`

how to add in a new column in select statement and assign a random number?

or

have any better solution?

Comment: The DB is no place for randomness. Pick a random ID from your app then pull that record. Then you can implement random-except logic for the later questions.

Comment: hmmm...have to save the ID i had picked in a array, that is complicate

Comment: If programming were easy, everyone would do it. Besides, you don't need the ID; just order by id and use offset x limit 1, then you only need to know the total count.

Comment: How about you get the MySQL array from the DB and then use $array =shuffle($array); Then a foreach($array as $question)

Comment: Like Dave said you don't want to randomize it in the DB and even if you do it will still order it by the random number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a RAND() function in MySQL which goes like `FLOOR(RAND() * (<max> - <min> + 1)) + <min>`.

So suppose you want to generate a random number between 1 to 500, you can hit a query like

```
SELECT t.*, 
       Floor(Rand() * 500) + 1 AS Random_ID 
FROM   tbl_question t 
ORDER  BY random_id
```

This should work. All the best.

Comment: How about accepting the answer then.. :D

Comment: Remaining 5 Minutes to Accept the Answer, =) thanks ya

Comment: What happens if you delete an answer, an id may be missing?